# how to configure multiple consumer in a single queue in weblogic server 10.3.6

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I have a JMS module setup with 10 consumers running in weblogic 10.3.6. In weblogic console i can see 10 consumers are active.But when i am feeding multiple message in the targeted queue, message are consuming one after another(i.e after a consumer receive a message and after finishing all the work then only second message get read by consumer all though other 9 consumers are free at that time.